# How to add a text watermark to multiple videos with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am currently using this command to output all videos in folder without the first 5 seconds:

```
FORFILES /M "*.mkv" /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -ss 5.5 -i  ^"@file^" -c copy -map 0 ^"done\\@file^""
```

I would like to know how can I add a text watermark to all of them in the same command. The location of the watermark should be on top left of the video.

Comment: Use [`drawtext` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1)

Comment: I can do 1 video with this command  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf delogo=x=11:y=9:w=152:h=32 -c:a copy output.mkv   how can I combine it with the trimming one?

Comment: just add the `-vf` option to your command anywhere after `-i  ^"@file^"`

Comment: Thanks man! I already did that before but it did not work, ran the file from cmd and it was the -c copy giving an error, seems like it does not work with the -vf command, removed it and it's all good now!

Comment: right, you cannot filter and copy. You must re-encode. so `-c:a copy` to copy only audio

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to add a text in place of the removed watermark with the same dimensions specified in the command above, what what the command be for adding a text watermark? Thanks again!

Comment: See the link off my very first comment.